# Adding greek symbol (pi) on the axis tick mark of a plot

Tags: r

I want to print the greek alphabet (multiple of) pi in the x-label tick mark of a histogram in R.
Specifically, let us consider the example:

```
x=runif(100,0,pi)
hist(x,freq = F)
```

[image]

Now how to print actual expression of (0,pi/7,pi/6,pi/5,pi/4,pi/3,pi/2,pi)
at the x axis tick mark instead of (0,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5) in the above plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand, that with "label" you actually mean "tick mark". Otherwise see the answer given by ira. You may want to change the `at=` part to something more appropriate.

```
x=runif(100,0,pi)
hist(x, xaxt="n")
axis(side=3, at=c(0,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5),
     labels=c("0","pi/7","pi/6","pi/5","pi/4","pi/3","pi/2","pi"))
axis(side=1, at=c(0,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5),
     labels=c("0",expression(pi/7),expression(pi/6),expression(pi/5),
          expression(pi/4),expression(pi/3),expression(pi/2),
          expression(pi)))
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, I wanted to mean tick mark. Your answer provide the all that I wanted to. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
x=runif(100,0,pi)
hist(x,freq = F, xlab = expression(pi), xaxt = "n")
axis(1, at = c(0,pi/4,pi/2,3*pi/4,pi),
     c("0",expression(pi/4),expression(pi/2),expression(3*pi/4),
       expression(pi)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.